# CodeIgniter is returning an unauthorized for a new page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I set up a new page to do validation on a cron job that runs in the CodeIgniter framework that I been setting up a management system on.

Setting up the validation page as

```
class Cron_Validate extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){
        echo "BOO";
    }
}
```

to test it and when I run it on the development machine it returns a 404 and changes the url to unauthorized.

```
"localhost/index.php/cron_validate"
```

is what I type.

```
"localhost/index.php/unauthorized"
```

is what shows.

For the life of me I cant figure out why the controller is marking it as unauthorized. 
I am not trying to display information so views are not necessary.

This is eluding me and I need to get the unauthorized to go away and start displaying the debugging info that I need.

-EDIT UPDATE
I searched the database and configuration files to see if there was possibly a list of permitted pages and no dice.

Seeing as its a local development copy and I just need it to run so I can debug the code itself I even tried removing the .htaccess file to see if that was the culprit, it was not the culprit.

I finally found it. it was in check_authority function 
which can be found in 
 application/hooks/authority.php

I had to put in an exception for the specific page or specify credentials sufficient to the task at hand. Since it was a cron job that was going to be fired there were no credentials to be passed, I put in an exception for the specific page. I am sure this will raise alarms of a possible exploit but for now it gets the job done and runs fine with the .htaccess restored and all other security in place.

Comment: You should only allow the process to run if you know it is being requested locally. For example, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='127.0.0.1'` or something similar.

Comment: I guess your new set up (new machine) is set up differently...

Comment: there is no real way for anyone to run this unless they know the specific url, secondly its a validation sequence, would not matter if it ran every 3 minutes, I flip a flag in the database when the record itself is processed. I also scrub the data before inserting any data for possible sql injection.

It was the same, it was just that I wanted the page to utilize the codeigniter framework to make the connections to the database (Rather not have multiple points of access to the database.)